# How to optimize leaflet path?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I have a path that has over 13,000 lat/lon points.  Testing locally it works fine, but once on a device it's SUPER taxing and laggy. The path is so dense because the path has been snapped to roads.

What can I do in order to optimize things so my app runs more smoothly?  Define the path densities based on zoom level??  How can I do this?

Comment: Many GIS databases have functions for polygon simplification. What is your primary data source?

Comment: I'm just using google maps to layout the path.  Are there some tools you could recommend that might help?

Comment: Using google maps? Please elaborate

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet has a `smoothFactor` option for `L.Polyline` vectors:

> How much to simplify the polyline on each zoom level. More means better performance and smoother look, and less means more accurate representation.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline-smoothfactor

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your path as a GeoJSON file, for example using the online tool [mapshaper](http://www.mapshaper.org/). The website is pretty straight-forward to use.

Simplifying from the source also saves downloading time, rather than fetching the entire 13k points and simplifying in the client with Leaflet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a javascript solution [geojson-mend](https://github.com/deathg0d/geojson-mend). Ex usuage:

```
var geomend = require("geojson-mend");
var isMended = geomend.nReduce(<GEOJSON OBJECT>, <TOLERANCE>);
console.log(isMended);
```

Replace `<GEOJSON OBJECT>` with your GeoJSON object and the `<TOLERANCE>` with the resolution you want. `0.0001` is roughly equal to `11.1m`.

In your scenario, you could use a variation of this plugin to get and save different levels of details on zoom level change?